# Adding stylesheet in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I would like to ask why my stylesheet is not showing on the page source of the webpage. Please see the code below, that's the code in my functions.php.

```
`function theme_styles() {

        wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    }

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme-styles' );`
```

I believe I have entered the code correctly but whenever I right click on the webpage and look for the source code, my stylesheet is not showing. I am using WebMatrix by the way and my **style.css** is under the themes folder that I am currently working on. I am new in WordPress and I'm trying to create my own custom theme. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you so much,

Gilbert Jacob

Answer (score 2):

Try This :

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'themename-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function my_theme_load_resources() {
    $theme_uri = get_template_directory_uri();
    wp_register_style('style_css', $theme_uri.'/style.css', false, '0.1');
    wp_enqueue_style('style_css');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_load_resources');
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I noticed that my theme_styles is using an underscore and the one I use in action is theme-styles. Thanks!